# How can I call a image from resources by using a string instead of its file name in c#?

Tags: c#, resources

I am writing an uncrating simulator for Dirty Bomb in c# and need some new lines of code as I need to be able to call an image from resources using the number that the program outputs through the use of a random number generator.
Here is the ClickButton code:

```
void OpenClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cases = cases + 1;
            Random Cards = new Random();
            label33.Text = cases.ToString();
            if (case_settings == false)
            {
                credits = credits + 1000;
                label3.Text = credits.ToString();
                int Standard = Cards.Next(1, 1000);
                if (Standard <= 800)
                {
                    int Lead = Cards.Next(1, 153);
                    lead = lead + 1;
                    label34.Text = lead.ToString();
                    string card_lead = Lead.ToString();
                    Card.ImageLocation = card_lead + ".png";
                    if (Lead <= 9)
}}}
```

I have called the image from the bin folder just to get it to appear but I need this to work from resources, plus this is due in tomorrow, so any help would be grateful.